# mod_rewrite and 301 redirect in the same htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule (.*)$ ./page.php?name=$1
```

I also have about 20 different static addressess I want to do a 301 redirect to.

It should look something like:

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/category.php?id=3 http://www.example.com/books
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/articles.php?id=124 http://www.example.com/birds
```

I tried every method and failed.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What should be happening?  What is happening?  What's not happening?

Comment: a quick search for `mod_rewrite` in `phpinfo()` will tell you if you have the `mod_rewrite` module loaded. If you don't see it, then you need to ask your server company to add it.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error. I have mod_rewrite on my server as it is working. The problem is with adding a 301 redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your after a set of **SEO friendly URL's** for those in your **redirect** examples, if this is the case then you don't want a browser redirect, instead you want an Internal Redirect or Alias e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^/?books /category.php?id=3    [L]
RewriteRule ^/?birds /articles.php?id=124  [L]
```

If you have many rules and have access to the **httpd.conf** you may want to consider a rewrite map file and rule.

Per your comment BELOW, if you want to force users/crawlers to the new URL structure then you'll need an additional set of Rewrite rules in the file (not redirects) e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      /category\.php     [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^id=3  [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*                 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/books?   [R=301,L]
```

**FYI:** The Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation is worth a read if your unclear as to what the above rules do, or if you want something a little more abstract consider the following [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_4043.html).

Comment: Exactly the other way around. May htaccess file is now handling SEO friendly URL's. The problem is when I want to turn old addresses to new friendly URL addresses. For some reason my htaccess file won't except 2 RewriteRule sentences in the same file.

Comment: Would have helped if you saif that in your question, have updates the answer above, to reflect.

Comment: This works great. Just one issue: for some reason the redirect you did will point me to http://www.example.com/books?id=3. Is it possible to get rid of the query string in the result?

Comment: Yes, a QSD in the options or a ? in the target will do it, will tweak the answer

Comment: A QSD in the options created a 50 errorbut the ? worked perfectly. Thanks Again.